# Alignment negative x tick labels PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, ticks, axis

I'd like to ask if there is a way how to align negative xtick labels (those with "minus" sign), so they are alligned as like as positive ones (green box on the picture). I mean the number is aligned straight under the tick and "minus" is ignored with alignment. The negative number alignment on the picture (red box) looks simply awful.

Minimal WME:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%
\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}%

\begin{semilogyaxis}[
log plot exponent style/.style={
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
/pgf/number format/precision=1},
domain=-5:10]%

\addplot {exp(x)};%

\addplot {exp(2*x)};%

\legend{$e^x$,$e^{2x}$}%

\end{semilogyaxis}%

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

[image: Red box awful alignment, green box nice alignment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility using `xticklabel`. I added some comments in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  log plot exponent style/.style={
  /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
  /pgf/number format/precision=1},
  domain=-5:10,
  width=\linewidth,
  xticklabel={
    % test if the x value is below zero
    \ifdim \tick pt < 0pt
      % if yes, calculate the absolute value
      \pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}%
      % and print first a minus sign in a zero-width box, followed by the absolute value
      \llap{$-{}$}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
   \else
     % if no, print as usual
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}
   \fi
}
]%

\addplot {exp(x)};
\addplot {exp(2*x)};

\legend{$e^x$,$e^{2x}$}

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for quick answer! 
I slighty modified Your post and use it more generally as:
/pgfplots/xticklabel={\ifdim\tickpt<0pt\pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}\llap{$-{}$}pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}elsepgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi}